# Adding _meta in elasticsearch mapping require reindexing?

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql

Does adding _meta in elasticsearch require reindexing?

I currently have a situation where I need to add the *_meta* field in elasticsearch. I have tried it locally, it worked like a charm without the need of reindexing the data. But I need complete clarity on the same that if in any case, it would destroy the data or not?

I have gone through the elastic documentation that reindexing is recommended only if the mapping of existing field changes.

Please confirm on the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `_meta` to the mapping does not require reindexing because the documents are untouched, you're only adding metadata at the mapping level, nothing else.